# pycuda.driver module not found

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have installed `python 3.7.2` along with the following libraries: `jupyter`, `pandas`, `numpy`, `pytools` and `pycuda`. I'm working with `Visual Studio Code`. I'm trying to run the standard `pyCuda` example:

```
# --- PyCuda initialization
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

# --- Create a 4x4 double precision array of random numbers
import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)

# --- Demote array to single precision
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)

# --- Allocate GPU device memory
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)

# --- Memcopy from host to device
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

# --- Define a device function that doubles the input device array
mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void doublify(float *a)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
    a[idx] *= 2;
  }
  """)

# --- Define a reference to the __global__ function and call it
func = mod.get_function("doublify")
func(a_gpu, block=(4,4,1))

# --- Copy results from device to host
a_doubled = numpy.empty_like(a)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_doubled, a_gpu)

print(a_doubled)
print(a)
```

When I run this code, `VSCode` says that

```
Module 'pycuda.driver' has no 'mem_alloc' member
Module 'pycuda.driver' has no 'memcpy_htod' member
Module 'pycuda.driver' has no 'memcpy_dtoh' member
```

However, from the below figure, it seems that the module exists

[image]

Any suggestion on how solving the problem?

**EDIT: SIMPLIFIED TEST CASE**

If I run

```
# --- PyCuda initialization
import pycuda.driver as cuda

print("test")
```

then `test` is emitted in the console. If I run

```
# --- PyCuda initialization
import pycuda.driver as cuda

# Initialize CUDA
cuda.init()

print("test")
```

nothing is emitted in the console and `VSCode` emits the following `problem`

```
Module 'pycuda.driver' has no 'init' member
```

Comment: I don't see any python runtime errors in this question, just IDE limitations. Does the code actually run? And if it does not, what python runtime error is emitted?

Comment: @talonmies Thank you for your interest in the question. I have edited my question with a simpler test case. If i try to run modules from the `pycuda.driver` it rises issues.

Comment: If I operate from the command prompt `>>>` and run `import pycuda.driver as cuda` and `cuda.init()`, then `python` just exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an installation issue.

I have just uninstalled the version of `pycuda` that I previously installed via

```
python pip install pycuda
```

and downloaded a precompiled binary from [Christoph Golke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda) page, while taking care of compatibility. For me, the correct file has been `pycuda-2018.1.1+cuda100-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64` for `python 3.7.2` `64bits`.

Now, everything works correctly.

Comment: It would be good if you could accept this to get the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs without `AttributeError`s then it is likely that Visual Studio is giving false positives. If so, ignore them. This happens because doing static analysis on dynamic code doesn't always do the right thing.

Comment: What does Python say when you try to run it? What is the stack trace?

Comment: I have edited the question with a simpler test case. Basically, if I try to run modules from the `pycuda.driver`, `VSCode` stops the execution and raises issues.

Comment: It's very difficult respond to "VScode raises issues". Try running your program from the command line and report what the Python interpreter says the problem is.

Comment: If I operate from the command prompt `>>>` and run `import pycuda.driver as cuda` and `cuda.init()`, then `python` just exits.

Comment: And if you run your program from a console command prompt? In other words, `python.exe myprogram.py`